# React Native: Check if targeted iphone is mini or not

Tags: ios, react-native

any possible way we can check if targeted device is a mini version of Iphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any thing useful that would give a discrete answer to a mini version. I've used [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info) with ***getDeviceName*** method and using this custom method to determine the small/mini version.

```
getDeviceName()
      .then((model) => {
        dispatch({
          type: IS_SMALL_PHONE,
          payload: model.includes('mini') || model.includes('Mini') || model.includes('SE'),
        });
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to find is [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info) and `getDeviceId()`.